# Unable to connect to MYSQL on a remote computer

Tags: mysql

I am working on windows and having a remote desktop connection of another machine. I am trying to connect to the mysql running on the remote machine through my MySql workbench, installed on my machine.

When I specify the details to connect to mysql i.e. 
              IP- a.b.c.d
              port-3306
              username=root
              password=

But everytime it shows me an error saying-

```
   Your connection attempt to connect to user='root'failed from your host to server at a.b.c.d:3306
```

Is it possible that I can connect to mysql on a different machine?

Comment: Yes, you need to add a user in MySQL with the IP of the client machine

Comment: check your firewall at database server allowed port 3306 or TCP/IP port

Comment: @Bojangles, I created a user with all the privileges  but still the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly that is possible, mysql is a network transparent service. However obviously the normal access authorization rules apply.

- do you have network access to the mysql port, this might be blocked by a firewall. You can check that by using `telnet ip-address-of-server 3306`. Does the server answer or do you get a timeout or are blocked? (the answer would look cryptic, soomething like ``` 5.5.33-MariaDB[*[n7p~g!�iXccI$r9``Y{$mysql_native_password ``` or similar )
- the mysql server can be configured to not listen to remote connections. This can add security to the setup, but would obviously block any remote connection attempts. You will have to check the configuration files of mysql for that.
- mysql itself implements an authorization level. So check if that 'root' user actually is allowed to connect from the outside. Those authorizations are stored in the internal "mysql" database.

Also it is not clear from the question what your network topology is: is the mysql server running on that system you have a "remote connection" to? Is the mysql-workbench running on *that remote* system or on your *local* system? This might affect the ip address you have to use inside the workbench.

Comment: MYSQL server is running on the remote machine also and workbench is installed on my machine.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification, you should add those details to the question. So you have to test if you have network access to the mysql port at all as I mentioned (first bullet).